# Increase index of pandas DataFrame by one

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to have my dataframe start with index 1 instead of 0. But somehow I am not getting it:

```
In[1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[4,7],[10,11],[7,2]],columns=['one', 'two'])
In[2]: df
Out[2]: 
   one  two
0    4    7
1   10   11
2    7    2
In[3]: df.reindex(range(1,len(df)+1))
Out[3]: 
   one  two
1   10   11
2    7    2
3  NaN  NaN
```

Where did my first row go? What am I getting wrong about reindex()?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reindexing does not reassign the index values and preserve the order for that you can assign directly:

```
In [25]:

df.index = range(1,len(df)+1)
df
Out[25]:
   one  two
1    4    7
2   10   11
3    7    2
```

The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas.DataFrame.reindex) show that you are conforming your data to the new index which will introduce `NaN` values where none existed hence why you lost a row, this is why there is a `fillna` param for `reindex`.

Answer (score 15):

To increase your index with 1 you can simply modify the index like this, `df.index += 1`.

Full example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([[4,7],[10,11],[7,2]],columns=['one', 'two'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   one  two
0    4    7
1   10   11
2    7    2

In [4]: df.index += 1

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   one  two
1    4    7
2   10   11
3    7    2
```

Comment: Note: `df.index += 1` results in a `IntXXIndex` whereas `df.index = df.index + 1` results in `RangeIndex`.

Comment: @Dataman Which one is "better"?

Comment: @problemofficer: I would say the one that preserves the original type. I am checking this using `pandas` version `1.1.3` and the `type(df.index)` is `<class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'>`. So, I would have said `df.index = df.index + 1` is better. But interesting thing is that I cannot reproduce my comment in version `1.1.3`. Both ways end up with `<class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'>`. So, now I would say both are as good while `df.index += 1` requires less typing! :)